# iOS Facebook Share with Link, Photo and Description in the same share dialog

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-sharer, slcomposeviewcontroller

After the iOS 11 relase, the SLComposeViewController is depraceted/not allowed sharing. So iOS developers have to use native Facebook and Twitter SDK to share content. And my problems is raising from this point.

I have been developing a new app which is needed facebook sharing with link, photo and description.  i have done separately sharing with photo or link with native FBSDK. But i want to ask you, anyone know how can i use photo and link and description in the same Facebook Dialog. Because in my scenario, i have to share discount detail with discounting shop web site(https://emregurses.com/....../shoes), and discount foto(shoes or bag) and the detail text(Hurry up, you can buy until the midnight)

You can see below codes which i use to share separately.

**Photo Share**

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
shareButton = [[FBSDKShareButton alloc] init];


if (shareImage) {
    FBSDKSharePhoto *sharePhoto = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
    sharePhoto.caption = facebookTitle;
    sharePhoto.image = shareImage;

    FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
    content.photos = @[sharePhoto];
}

shareButton.shareContent = content;
[shareButton sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

**Link Share**

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
    shareButton = [[FBSDKShareButton alloc] init];

    if (facebookUrl) {
        content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:facebookUrl];
    }else{
        content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://fastpay.com.tr/"];
    }

    shareButton.shareContent = content;
    [shareButton sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

But i want to share all of them in the same FBShare dialog as the before SLComposeViewController. Also imageURL property is deprecated the new SDK.

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSURL *imageURL
  DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE("`imageURL` is deprecated from Graph API 2.9");
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can not share predefined text via facebook share**.this is the limitation by facebook you can read more [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios)

> Use of the iOS share sheet is subject to Facebook Platform Policy,
>   including section 2.3 which states that apps may not pre-fill in the
>   context of the share sheet. This means apps may not pre-fill the share
>   sheet's initialText field with content that wasn't entered by the user
>   of the app.

Comment: Thank you @seggy. i read it. What about the link and photos? Can we share link and photos in the same pop -up dialog?

Comment: No, you cannot share link and photos in the same popup dialog. you can share only image or url in same.

Comment: @EmreGürses  is this helpful for you?

Comment: No!. Because i said before, I know we can not share in same dialog. You said same thing. But i asked you, anyone can done this for different way. @seggy